# PHP revert DateInterval back to string

Tags: php, mariadb, dateinterval

The php class DateInterval has its specific format of input such as

```
new DateInterval('P2Y4DT6H8M');
```

Is there any way to revert it, meaning to get from the `DateInterval` instance the originally formatted input:

```
'P2Y4DT6H8M'
```

(for example to be stored in database)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251587/is-it-possible-to-get-the-interval-spec-string-from-dateinterval-object

Comment: See the function `to_seconds` in http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php .